# How can I send the requests, container and system logs to application insights from my container app in azure functions

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, containers

I have created a function app using a container image (it is a python application), how ever I can't see any stats or logs to the connected application insights.

In my python app, i have this line of codes to target the application insights where i want my error logs to be logged.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string=os.getenv("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING")))
logger.info(f'------ Loading function {__name__} ------')
```

I have this setting in my host.json file

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": 
  {
    "http": 
    {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I can see though the error logs that I specifically coded to be logged in the logs blade and query "traces", but not the info logs.

[image]

Comment: can you share your function code?

Comment: which part of it? its a big code.

Comment: You can send me redacted one

Comment: Maybe this will work, create the most basic fastapi application and for logging, i refered to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789417/azure-application-insights-logging-for-python-application-set-exception-proper, then containerized it and deploy that to an azure function.

Comment: Do you wish to do the logging using code because you even can achieve it using portal. I am able to see the requests and function related logs in application insight by enabling it in Function App--> Function--> Monitor. By doing so, I am to see the logs like [this](https://i.imgur.com/LqK8qWT.png)

Comment: Did you deploy code as a container? because i cant see that in a container type deployment.

Comment: can you share your function app [this](https://i.imgur.com/EQMkOvJ.png) page

Comment: How did you create the function app where you have deployed your function? You have selected code or container image from the [template](https://i.imgur.com/xinpJ4g.png)

Comment: container image

Comment: are you able to see this [page](https://i.imgur.com/EQMkOvJ.png) and **Monitor** underneath?

Comment: No, should it appear there even if the app is inside the container?

Comment: Yes, Once you deploy your function to the function app, you will be able to see that function in the overview tab

Comment: I have created the function app in [this](https://i.imgur.com/zgjORVj.png) way and I am enabling application insight like [this](https://i.imgur.com/qOiJ3P5.png)

Comment: ill try this, im using app service plan

Comment: Yes, In app service plan also you will be able to enable application insight in the same way or even you can enable it while creating function app in [here](https://i.imgur.com/7ZkE8wx.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255645/discussion-between-jcm-and-ikhtesam-afrin).